# Deleting an SVN branch on Android Studio(windows)

Tags: android-studio, svn

I have SVN connected with Android studio (Windows), now I want to delete branch from my repositories. How i can do it with Android Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **VCS | Browse Subversion Repository** and run **Delete** context-menu command to remove the branch.

Note that Android Studio is based on [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/meet-intellij-idea.html). Therefore IDEA's documentation should also work for Android Studio. Read this help topic:

- [SVN Repositories Window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/svn-repositories.html)